# Server environment - Entity database first connects to db but not with entity code first

Tags: entity-framework, connection-string

I have a code first entity framework project, the connection string locally is as below, and I manage to connect and work successfully.

```
<add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnet-ASicav-20170830125528.mdf;Initial Catalog=aspnet-ASicav-20170830125528;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

Changing the Data Source to the name of the SQL Server of the server, does not work, neither do the million different combinations I tried. For e.g. I tried:

```
<add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=WEB1;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnet-ASicav-20170830125528.mdf;Initial Catalog=aspnet-ASicav-20170830125528;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

where WEB1 is the SQL Server name, and also tried to use ., which refers to the local machine and is used in various other websites hosted on the same server

```
<add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=.;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnet-ASicav-20170830125528.mdf;Initial Catalog=aspnet-ASicav-20170830125528;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

I also tried the below connection string:

The error I am getting is:

> 11/3/2017 7:16:37 PM: A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified)

Just to be clear, I managed to fix this issue by recreating the project using the usual database first approach, in fact the below config works OK in this environment (**of course using the same database in both cases**):

```
<add name="ASicavEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/ASicav.csdl|res://*/ASicav.ssdl|res://*/ASicav.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=.;initial catalog=ASicav;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

I also tried the above connection string in the code first environment. Again, it did not work, and same error.

but naturally, I would like to know why I am only managing with db first! Any ideas?

Comment: Show the connection string that is NOT working. You've got `Integrated Security=True` so make sure that account has access. Are you deploying the project or running from VS? If VS, can you connect via server explorer?

Comment: I am publishing the files and deploying the project on the server. The connection string I listed in the question is the one generated in the published solution and I tried to use it and change the name of the data source to the name of the SQL server and also . - which is used in various other cases for other projects hosted on the same server. The same database connects properly to a different variation of the project (database first) and the account does have access. Ill edit the post with more connection strings attempts soon!

Comment: OK, be aware that if you are deploying to a server and using integrated security you will need to setup an Active Directory account the application can use to connect, otherwise use SQL Security with a user id and password. https://gilesey.wordpress.com/2013/05/11/allowing-iis-7-5-applications-to-communicate-to-sql-server-via-windows-authentication/

Comment: Yes I do have the IIS APPPOOL\ApplicationPoolName user in the database also, in fact it would not have worked in the db first approach if I hadn't! BTW, as promised I updated the question with some other attempts and more info. thanks for your time !